# EF Core .ThenInclude does not include foreign entity and causes query to retrieve nothing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-3.0

I have an EF Core project here, but I do have difficulties with multilevel includes. I'm trying to query entries which do relate like this:

1. There's a mapping table for "friend" relationships from accountid to accountid. So layer one is this mapping entity.
2. The IDs of the accounts in the mapping table are foreign keys relating to the respective Account entity.
3. Within the account entity, there's a foreign key to an account online state entity.

So tl;dr; `FriendsMappingTable -> Account -> AccountOnlineState`.

Here's the code I do use:

```
public Task<List<TEntity>> Read(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>>[] foreignIncludes) 
{
    return RunInContextWithResult(async dbSet =>
    {
        var query = dbSet.Where(predicate);

        query = foreignIncludes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => include(current));

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    });
 }

private async Task<List<TEntity>> RunInContextWithResult([NotNull] Func<DbSet<TEntity>, Task<List<TEntity>>> dbFunc)
{
    await using var ctx = GetContext();

    return await dbFunc(ctx.Set<TEntity>());
}
```

and here's my call to that:

```
var friends = await m_friendsMappingRepository.Read(
            x => x.Id == sessionContext.Account.Id,
            x => x.Include(y => y.Friend).ThenInclude(y => y.AccountOnlineStateEntity));
```

However, with this setup, the query will just return nothing at all. If I remove the `.ThenInclude()`, it will at least return a corresponding friend entity for the given account, with the `OnlineState` entity set to null.

Here are the (stripped down) entities:

```
public interface IEntity<TKeyType>
{
    [NotNull]
    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public TKeyType Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("FriendsMapping")]
public class FriendsMappingEntity : IEntity<int>
{
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public AccountEntity Account { 
        get; 
        [UsedImplicitly] private set;
    }

    [Column("FriendId")]
    [ForeignKey("Friend")]
    public int FriendId { get; set; }

    public AccountEntity Friend
    {
        get; 
        [UsedImplicitly] private set;
    }
}

public class AccountEntity : IEntity<int>
{
    [ForeignKey("AccountOnlineStateEntity")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CanBeNull]
    public AccountOnlineStateEntity AccountOnlineStateEntity { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public List<FriendsMappingEntity> FriendsTo { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public List<FriendsMappingEntity> FriendsFrom { get; set; }
}

public class AccountOnlineStateEntity : IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("OnlineState")]
    public AccountOnlineState OnlineState { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Code is not screenshots. So, please learn how to format your code as code in stackoverflow.

Comment: @TomTom You're right... Done

Comment: Relationship (mapping) between `AccountEntity` and `AccountOnlineStateEntity` looks suspicious. Don't you have dedicated FK property/column in `AccountEntity`? Mapping says the PK `Id` is also a FK, which I doubt and in fact can incorrectly filter the result because `Include` adds `inner join` in this case.

Comment: @IvanStoev 's suggestion makes a lot of sense. I think, by adding an inverse property to the AccountOnlineState, that your relationship would be done up correctly and after a migration should be everything you need to include the related data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Building on Ivan's suggestion, add an InverseProperty and remove the ForeignKey from Account.Id.

```cs
    //[ForeignKey("AccountOnlineStateEntity")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CanBeNull]
    [InverseProperty("Account")
    public AccountOnlineStateEntity AccountOnlineStateEntity { get; set; }
```

And add a property to AccountOnlineStateEntity

```cs
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public AccountEntity Account { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, no luck though. As to what I want to achieve: Basically I just want to get a hold of the online state. As of now, I have two results: If I skip the foreigninclude, I get the account with the onlinestate entity set to null. If I add I, I just get 0 results at all.

Comment: So if x is the FriendsMappingEntity then I was missing the include(y=>y.account), I'm guessing you tried adding that because my query wasn't complete? I'm not sure what is causing the related data to be null. I took this code from one of my projects where I use this all the time.